# How do I set the target platform for a call to SolutionBuild.BuildProject in VisualStudio2012 package

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, vs-extensibility

I have a solution which is set up with a load of projects that are built with nmake. I am trying to write an extension for VS2012 that just calls build on the startup project set in the IDE as the basic f5 build active project is often not the startup project. I have managed to retrieve the startup project by finding all the projects from the EnvDTE.Solution interface, and comparing the uniquenames to those found in the Solution.StartupProjects collection and utilised the Solution.SolutionBuild.BuildProject function. However, my solution can be built for both win32 and x64 platforms and this function has no method of setting which one is to be built, only the configuration can be specified. The net result being that no matter what platform I have set in the IDE it always builds the Win32 platform. If I retrieve the EnvDTE80.SolutionConfiguration2 interface from the ActiveConfiguration method then it shows that the ActiveConfiguration has the correct platform.  Have I missed a method for building either the startup project, a specific project utilising the ActiveConfiguration or a method of specifying the platform as well?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

See the Articles about build configurations / platforms section on my web site.

http://www.visualstudioextensibility.com/articles/add-ins/

Specifically, start with:

HOWTO: Get or set the active solution configuration/platform from a Visual Studio add-in

Comment: Thank you for responding to my question, I actually came across your pages when I was researching the problem and they are very helpful. However nothing I read there resolve the issue I am having. To restate it, there seems to be two methods of issuing a build, via the SolutionBuild.Build() method, and SolutionBuild.BuildProject().  Build will build the entire solution, and BuildProject ignores the platform set in the active configuration.  I don't need to set the active platform as that is already done in the IDE, but I do need a way of telling BuildProject() to build the correct platform.