# Is there a way to automate build order for specific projects in a solution?

Tags: visual-studio, build, visual-studio-2017

I'm using a visual studio 2017. Our team has a consolidated solution with a lot of projects in it with a lot of dependencies. We are working on a new project and I wonder if there is any way (maybe a tool or a script) to build specific projects (**not the entire solution**) in a specific order?.
Currently in order to build we do it manually.

Comment: Maybe you can create a new control project. Editing the csproj file and give it a try. Similar to [this issue](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f0bda9d9-60b7-416d-826d-df507945d0db/restore-nuget-packages-via-msbuild2017-fails-for-a-vs-extension-project-type-beckhoff-twincat?forum=msbuild).

Comment: What kind of dependencies? If the dependencies are specified via project references, MSBuild can handle that automatically.

Comment: @LexLi my team and I didn't specified the dependencies of the new projects yet (the reason for that is because it might change in the future, and from experience it's complicated to change dependencies between projects after those projects were built), so in the meanwhile we want an option that can build only those projects files in a specific order instead of doing it manually.

Comment: It’s too broad to tell what to do at this stage, and it is also not a good idea to split a solution into too many small projects.

Comment: @LexLi I agree with you it's not a good behavior... but still it consumes a lot of time to build manually every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SolutionBuild.BuildProject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.solutionbuild.buildproject?view=visualstudiosdk-2017#EnvDTE_SolutionBuild_BuildProject_System_String_System_String_System_Boolean_) method and call it from [Visual Commander](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/) like this:

```
public class C : VisualCommanderExt.ICommand
{
    public void Run(EnvDTE80.DTE2 DTE, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package package) 
    {
        EnvDTE.SolutionBuild builder = DTE.Solution.SolutionBuild;
        builder.BuildProject("Debug", @"C:\ClassLibrary\WindowsFormsApp1\WindowsFormsApp1.csproj", true);
        builder.BuildProject("Debug", @"C:\ClassLibrary\WpfApp1\WpfApp1.csproj", true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow! thank you @Sergey! you deserves more upvotes!.
I see you can decide the Solution Build Configuration (in your example "Debug"), I wonder if it is possible to decide the Solution Platforms for each Build (like x64\Any CPU)?

Comment: It is not possible with BuildProject: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35184304/how-do-i-set-the-target-platform-for-a-call-to-solutionbuild-buildproject-in-vis

Comment: It is probably possible to decide platform using SolutionConfiguration2.Activate() -> IVsSolutionBuildManager.FindActiveProjectCfg -> IVsProjectCfg.get_BuildableProjectCfg -> IVsBuildableProjectCfg.StartBuild, but is much more complex.

Answer (score 0):

You can build projects outside Visual Studio with [MSBuild](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild?view=vs-2017) for a specific configuration and platform:

```
"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" "C:\ClassLibrary\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2.vcxproj" /t:Build /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform="x64"
"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" "C:\ClassLibrary\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2.vcxproj" /t:Build /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform="Any CPU"
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using **Visual Studio's "External Tools"**
(Menu -> Tools -> External Tools...)

From the "External Tools..." you can invoke a script, that based on the passed arguments will build the needed projects. You need to write this script (for example .bat file) that will have the logic what projects need to be build based on the input arguments...

Read more here for the "External Tools" menu in VS:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/managing-external-tools?view=vs-2017

#### Passing arguments to the command

In the "External Tools" dialog, you can pass the needed arguments to the script

- the currently selected project as $(ProjectFileName)
- to specify the build configuration and platform (debug|release, Any CPU|x64|x86), tick the "Prompt for arguments" checkbox